# Vandermonde Determinant with one column replaced

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How to calculate the A(n) Vandermonde matrix determinant if the column with powers n-1 is replaced with powers n?

Comment: What have you tried in answering this question?

Comment: This line of thought leads to Schur polynomials.

Comment: I tried using the multilinearity of determinants, breaking them in two determinants. One normal vandermonde and the other with the leading column as {a^(n-1)}(a-1), to no avail.

Comment: Thank you! That pdf in the top answer had a nice solution.